# What to do with old question I don't care about anymore?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I asked a question related to a project that was active at the time. However, there were no good answers at the time, so I haven't accepted any answer.

Time goes on, the related project is finished… however, without solving the problem from the question.

Recently I've got some potentially good answers on that question. However, as the project is no longer active, I don't have time nor willingness to evaluate them. What should I do with that question now? I'm asking, because the question is a quite popular one—I've got a “Famous Question” badge for it, so it would be nice if some more effort was put into picking a proper answer. Should I just accept the answer that looks like the best one, or just leave the question without accepted answer?

Comment: Just leave it without accepted answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh I tend to disagree - I don't think it's a good thing to leave questions without an accepted answer. On the other hand one should not "accept" lightly arbitrary questions... This is a big dilemma...

Comment: @Shai: If the question generate enough views (Famous Question badge), then community votes are enough. There is no requirement that a question must have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

If the question hasn't been answered, don't accept it as answered.

You never know, someone could come up with the solution tomorrow, or someone else may encounter the same problem and offer a bounty for a more canonical answer (they may be less lightly to do this if an answer is already "accepted") leading to an answer.

Just because you're no longer interested in the question doesn't mean the rest of the world is :)

*Some people used to get annoyed with questions being left unaccepted (back when the user's accept-rate was published next to the question...!) Provided you **do** accept answers which **do** answer the question, you're using the site correctly.*

Comment: “Provided you do accept answers which do answer the question, you're using the site correctly.”—that's what I actually cannot do now. I no longer can evaluate whether the answer answers the question.

Comment: I just no longer work in the related technology, so I cannot check them empirically. And I was never an expert in the technology, so I cannot evaluate the answers without spending some time on them. That's all.

Comment: Do you not remember why it wasn't a valid answer? If another answerer has ago wait and see what the experts looking at the tag think. Or better yet, just leave it and forget about it (there are thousands of great questions which the OP hasn't accepted). Just don't fret about it :)

Comment: I'm not worrying about that. I just noticed there's no consensus on this issue, so I decided to fill the gap by posting this question.